# Does OpenEBS support or has any plugin for DCOS or MESOS?

Tags: mesos, dcos, openebs

Apart from kubernetes, I was wondering whether OpenEBS works on DCOS or MESOS? Or OpenEBS has any plugin support for them?

Answer (score 1):

currently, OpenEBS is tightly integrated to kubernetes only.